# Finding limit to $\lim_{x \to 2^+} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x-2)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to find limit for:
$$
\lim_{x \to 2^+} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x-2)}.
$$

The first thing that comes to mind is simplifying with $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin(x)/x = 1$; however, we have limit going to 2.

I tried to  first rewrite the expression with limit going to zero. We could do this by replacing $x$ with $t = x-2$:

$$\lim_{t \to 0^+} = \frac{\sin(t+2)}{(t+2)t}$$

But I get stuck here. The first instinct is to try and extract $\sin(x)/x$ from this expression to simplify it. But I have no idea how.

Comment: Where's the problem with your first expression? $\sin(x)/x$ is finite when $x$ approaches $2$. Before simplifying anything you should always test the limit.

Comment: this is not an indeterminate form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let be $x-2:=y$. We have

$$\lim_{x \to 2^+} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x-2)}=\lim_{y \to 0^+}\frac{\sin(y+2)}{y(y+2)}=\lim_{y \to 0^+}\frac{\sin(y+2)}{(y+2)}\cdot \lim_{y \to 0^+}\frac 1y=\frac{\sin 2}{2}\times (+\infty)=+\infty$$

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask why  $\lim_{y \to 0^+}\frac 1y=\infty$? In my text book whenever denominator is equal to zero, when limit is going to zero, it's considered indeterminate(?) and they seek to rewrite the expression in a way where denominator is not zero.

Comment: @LennyWhite You're welcome. You can try with a calculator. If the denominator of a fraction is always more little near to zero you can see that the calculator gives you a large number. Try it!!!!

Answer (score 2):

As noticed

$$\lim_{x\to2^+} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} = \dfrac{\sin(2)}{2}=c>0$$

$$\lim_{x\to2^+} \frac1{x-2}=\infty$$

and then

$$\lim_{x \to 2^+} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x-2)}=\lim_{x\to2^+} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}\frac1{x-2} = \infty$$

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't have anything special to do here, you have:

$$\lim_{x\to2^+} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} = \dfrac{\sin(2)}{2}$$

Which is a finite non-zero quantity. With that,

$$\lim_{x\to2^+} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x\cdot(x-2)} = \dfrac{\sin(2)}{2\cdot(x-2)} = +\infty$$

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask the logic behind $\dfrac{\sin(2)}{2\cdot(x-2)}$ being equal $+\infty$?

Comment: I'm a bit late, but if we take $\lambda = \dfrac{\sin(2)}{2} \ne 0$, then we see that $\dfrac{\lambda}{x - 2}$ will go to infinity because we are dividing by a quantity that approaches $0$.